# Glacier Bay Kitchen Faucet Cuts out

Tags: kitchens, faucet

After 3 years the Faucet just started cutting out when trying to get to a higher pressure. I can only go to about 1/3 of max.
I thought it might be the 3 way valve as most are plastic now. When to HD and got a new one put it back together and BAM, same thing. I saw a  thread here that suggested it was a plugged aerator. So I took the nozzle apart and it was clean, except for the out side (you know).

I know out here in Calif they have all kinds of dumb regulations on faucet and shower flow. But those are usually easy to remove.

So what causes a brand new valve to cut out? Is there some other kind of stupid stuff in the faucet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "cut out"; does the flow suddenly stop? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: When you say "higher pressure" do you actually mean higher flow, as in setting the faucet to max open setting? When you say "3 way valve", what are you describing, the faucet valve/cartridge, the wall stop-valve?

Comment: OMG, I made a mistake coming here. I thought it was a DIY help community.